# Android: ImageView.setImageResource is not displaying correct in gridviewadapter

Tags: android, gridview, getview

I define a gridview and gridviewadapter to choose images. When select 2 or more images, all work well. But, when I select 1, the position =1 is covered by images in positon = 0, and this only happen the first time to choose 1 image.  Flowing is getView() in adapter:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        L.d("mytest position ="+position+ "converView ="+convertView);
        Holder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, null);
            holder.mSelectImage = (NGImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (getData().size() > 0 && position != getData().size()) {
            holder.mSelectImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ImageItem imageItem = getData().get(position);
            if (imageItem != null) {
                if (imageItem.getImageUri().toString().startsWith("http")) {
                    loadNGImageView.LoadOptionsView(imageItem.getImageUri().toString(),holder.mSelectImage);

                } else {
                    String imgUrl = BitmapUtil.IMAGE_URI_SUFFIX_SDCARD + imageItem.getImageUri().getPath();
                    L.d("mytest LoadOptionsView");
                    loadNGImageView.LoadOptionsView(imgUrl,holder.mSelectImage);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (position == TopicPostFragment.DEFAULT_PHOTO_COUNT) {
                holder.mSelectImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.mSelectImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                L.d("mytest setImageResource");
                holder.mSelectImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.guild_icon_img);
            }

        }

        return convertView;
    }

error logs:
mytest position =0  converView =null
mytest setImageResource

mytest position =0  converView =android.widget.FrameLayout{42cd7de8 V.E.....    
......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0113 app:id/fl_item}
mytest setImageResource

                     ......

mytest position =0   converView =android.widget.FrameLayout{42eabc00 V.E..... 
........ 0,0-90,90 #7f0b0113 app:id/fl_item}
mytest LoadOptionsView

mytest position =1   converView =android.widget.FrameLayout{42cd7de8 V.E.....  
......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0113 app:id/fl_item}
mytest setImageResource
```

error display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dru9Z.png)

correct display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9FBL.png)

xml file：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fl_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please show xml View data.

Comment: I replace the line   holder.mSelectImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.guild_icon_img);   with code  loadNGImageView.LoadOptionsView("http://pic3.nipic.com/20090527/2488154_225452038_2.jpg",holder.mSelectImage);   everything goes well.  This shows setImageResource cannot really add image to imageview, why?

Comment: @Alexander  I have added the xml View data~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setImageResource cannot be used with setImageURL at the same time, sometimes setImageURL may cover setImageResource and make the wrong display. 
if you use them at the same time ,you should first setImageURL(null) ,then use setImageResource.